# How to view only contents of a website without the source content (HTML)?

Tags: curl, web

I tried using curl but it displays lot of HTML content (Source).

I wanted to know whether it is possible to view contents of the webpage - say a table with some information.

Comment: in a text window? like with lynx or such?

Comment: Yes. Tried using curl but it displays lot of HTML content that is not desired.

Comment: Give us more info and give feedback to current answers available.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `links`.

e.g. `links -width 512 -dump http://www.example.com/`

`links` is available pre-packaged for most, if not all linux distros, and the home page with source is at http://links.twibright.com/

`lynx` is another alternative, another text-mode browser with a `-dump` option.  Also packaged for most/all linux distros, and home page is at http://lynx.invisible-island.net/

Answer (score 1):

You may try [html2text](http://linux.die.net/man/1/html2text). If does not help, provide more info please.

Answer (score 0):

Open the source in e. g. LibreOffice Writer, you'll get the content and formatting in readable format and may be able to export it into other formats, too. However, if you want to script it you are better off with other solutions.